# Plot Data on Primary AND Secondary Axis

Tags: excel, graph

I am graphing 3 datasets on a graph with 2 x-axes and 2 y-axes.

I want:

- Series 1 to have Primary X, Primary Y
- Series 2 to have Secondary X, Secondary Y
- Series 3 to have Primary X, Secondary Y

Is it possible for Series 3 to be on a Primary x-axes and Secondary y-axes?  I only see the option for Primary or Secondary, which chooses the same for X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel does not offer a way to have a single data series plotted on both a primary and secondary axis.

I have had a few situations in the past requiring something similar, and my solution was pretty janky. I made a third graph, setting the x-axis the same as the Primary X in graph 1 and the y-axis the same as Secondary Y in graph 2. I then played with the formatting of graph 2 (removed fill, gridlines, axes, etc. so basically only the series data is visible) and then placed it on top of graph 1, creating the illusion that it was all one graph.

Sadly, this only really works if either the axis min/max values are static or you are willing to put in a bunch of tedious manual work each time you update the data.